# CreateFileW() handle returns -1

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8.1, driver, createfile

I am trying to create handle to Windows Phone device. But `CreateFileW` returns -1 and Error code is 3 `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND`. Any help to this problem?

My code:

```
handle = CreateFileW("\\\\.\\NOKIA_TOUCH", GENERIC_READ Or GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ Or FILE_SHARE_WRITE, IntPtr.Zero, 3, 0, IntPtr.Zero)
If handle = -1 Then
    ShowMsg(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error)
Else
    ShowMsg("Success!")
End If
```

**EDIT**: P/Invoke code:

```
<DllImport("kernelBase.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling:=False, PreserveSig:=True, SetLastError:=True)>
Public Shared Function CreateFileW(ByVal lpFileName As String, ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Integer, ByVal dwShareMode As Integer, ByVal lpSecurityAttributes As IntPtr, ByVal dwCreationDisposition As Integer, ByVal dwFLagsAndAttributes As Integer, ByVal hTemplateFile As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function
```

Comment: Can you [edit] this and show us the code for the p/Invoke?

Comment: That's C syntax, you don't escape the backslashes in Basic.  Use `"\\.\NOKIA_TOUCH"`

Comment: Thanks @hans-passant, but now error code is 2. `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

Comment: Well, sure, what are the odds that this can actually work?  Zilch when you don't document why you think this should work.

Answer (score 0):

This is unlikely to work (you probably don't have security capability to talk to the Nokia driver) and even if it does work while debugging on your device you won't be able to submit it to the Windows Store (unless you work for an OEM that needs to use this driver).

What are you trying to do with the driver that can't be done through the public API?

Comment: I'm not going to submit app to Store. I need access to driver because of capacitive buttons backlight controling.